GitHub Actions - checkout - Error: Parameter 'commandLine' cannot be null or empty
Getting the following error while checking out code on self-hosted windows 10 machine:
Error: Parameter 'commandLine' cannot be null or empty.
The workflow file contains the following steps:
steps:
  
  - name: Checkout Code
    uses: actions/checkout@v4
    with:
      fetch-depth: 0

  - name: Verify PowerShell Version
    run: pwsh -Command "$PSVersionTable"
    shell: pwsh
    
  - name: Debug Start
    run: echo "Starting the workflow"
    shell: cmd
    
  - name: Debug Checkout
    run: echo "Checkout completed"
    shell: cmd            

  - name: Verify Checkout
    run: echo "Checkout completed successfully"
    shell: cmd


https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/314

installed git on the host machine , but it did not change the previous outcome. Checked in the command line with "git --version" and it printed git version 2.46.0.windows.1

try to restart the runner (after the git installation)

Thanks, it works now! But should it be necessary to install git on the host runner. Should github action not have taken care of it ?

Awesome! apparently not :/

You need to install Git in your self-hosted machine (see here more details).
If the runner is already configured you need to restart it after the Git installation.
